# Call method by timer

Tags: java, android, timer, textview

I have a working method, which is changing text in a TextView.
I have copypasted it for running another method by timer - it is not working.
Please explain where is my problem?

```
public void timer(final int timel){                             
        ScheduledExecutorService service2 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        service2.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                alert();
            }
        }, timel, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
```

P.S. Of course method alert() is working (i can call it everywhere, but not there).

Alert function:
How i can use "static" for rows where i've put comment "HERE"?

```
public void alert(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);//HERE
if (tmp=="") //loading from FireBase
{
    chargeText = ":)";
}
        builder.setTitle(R.string.text)
                .setMessage(chargeText)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.gatsby)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.share,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                intent.setType("text/plain");
                                String textToSend= "Some text" + chargeText.toLowerCase() + ". Some text?";
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToSend);
                                try
                                {
                                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Description of method"));//HERE
                                }
                                catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//HERE
                                }
                            }
                        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.exit,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: Post some additional info like the code that triggers it.

Comment: @AakashVerma i am caling it in this way: `timer(8);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `YOURCLASS.alert();` because you are inside the Runnable now.

Comment: For using this i need to make my method static, so i have tried this:              `public void run() {
                MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
                ma.alert();
            }` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your alert() function. Can you make it static? What you have tried will not work.

Comment: You need to change `public void alert(){`to `public static void alert(){`. In what class did you define your alert() method?

Comment: yes, i've add 'static' word. In the same class where my timer() method is. Please tell me how i can use `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);` with `public static void alert()`?

Comment: because i am having error: `com...MainActivity.this' cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Are you sure that `MainActivity.alert();` inside your run() method didn't work when your alert()-function was not static? Is your alert() method in the MainActivity class?

Comment: yes, i'm sure because i've error: "Non-static method 'alert()' cannot be referenced from a static context" when i'm trying to use `MainActivity.alert();` when my alert()-function is'nt static. Yes, my alert() in the MainActivity class.